# iPhone App Submission - Rejecting Binary & Uploading New Binary

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

Currently an update to my iPhone application has been in review for over **10 days**!!!

In that period of time I've been able to work out a few bugs and even add some small new features to my application. I know that it is possible to reject your binary, but I would rather go a head a publish my application then send apple a better version 1.1.1...

So basically my question would be if I rejected my apps binary and submitted one right after would my app get pushed to the bottom of the review pile or would I keep my spot in line (since I've already been waiting for 10 days)?

Comment: Im not an iOS developer, but I know from reading dev comments that 10 days is really not exceptional for approval. If I were you Id expect to wait some more time. Theres an argument to say get it shipped as soon as possible, and summit any fixes later, but you risk a run of bad reviews, and then your app is basically dead in the water. Just ship the best product possible, and if that means waiting another month before its ready and approved, thats what you should do

Comment: @carpii Thanks! But the version I submitted before is in perfect working condition, just with 10 long days (and with my company only having one app currently) we had a lot of time to add new features...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, rejecting a binary and immediately resubmitting a new one will not maintain your place in line: you would be knocked back to the start of the queue. I base this on my own experience, having rejected and resubmitted binaries a few times in the past.

Now, you might be thinking: "OK, what about the expedited review process?"

I can share some experience with that: With my latest app, I was in the same position you were in but I decided to go ahead and release 1.0 and then submit 1.0.1 soon afterwards. When 1.0 was approved and released, Apple chose it for the "New & Noteworthy" section. All of a sudden the app was getting a lot of exposure—and complaints about a bug that I had fixed in 1.0.1. I submitted 1.0.1—and as well as a request for expedited review—which was approved. 1.0.1 was released about 24 hours later.

So, you'll have to weigh the pros and cons for your own app, but I hope this info helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would, rejecting and resubmitting the binary will place you at the bottom of the review queue. It's unfortunate, but there is no work around.

Answer (score 1):

If Apple allowed that then many devs would start uploading their beta version while trying to fix those last few bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had submitted my app and it was in review. I was asked to change some metadata and resubmit the app. While doing that, I discovered a UI issue and fixed it. I was in a dilemma as to keep the current binary and release a version 1.01 or upload the new version. I did not want to send my first app with an issue so, I went ahead and rejected the binary and uploaded the new one. I immediately contacted Apple developer technical support. They claim that "The review time will not be affected and that our internal systems do have process your build before it can be reviewed (verifying it’s general correctness and resigning your app for the store), which can add some delay.  However, that delay is fairly small and is only a minor factor in review time.  More to that point, any delay here is much smaller than the delay of a new submission." I  hope that is true and hope my app is not stuck in the "waiting for review or in review" limbo :(.